# Set python version for each virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Using virtualenv I can set the python version to a specific virtual environment via th `-p` option. This means for different environments I can set different python versions. Is there a similar possibility for virtualenvwrapper? Please note I dont want to set a system wide version used in ALL virtual environments. I would like to have the flexibility it to set the python version on virtual environment level.

Comment: Were you able to set a specific python version in virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the `-p` option when creating a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper to specify the version: `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 my_env`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found you can also do the same for virtualenvwrapper projects like so:
`mkproject -p python2 my_venv_project`.
Also, Make sure the project name comes last