# How can I install a particular version of python in virtualenwrapper?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I need a specific version of python (3.6) in a virtual enviroment using virtualenwrapper and i do not know how to do that. I created the virtual enviroment with the command(mkvirtualenv [mkvirtualenv-options] [virtualenv-options] ) later it comes the moment that i need that specific version (3.6).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set python version for each virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241188/set-python-version-for-each-virtualenv-using-virtualenvwrapper)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+different+python+version